# django on_delete not working

Tags: django, django-models

I am using [django-threadedcomments](https://github.com/HonzaKral/django-threadedcomments/) app, and since in the model given below parent is a foreign key of a threaded comment, it also gets deleted when I delete a comment. However I do not want that to happen. So I add `on_delete = models.SET_NULL` but this does not seem to be working. The parent comment still gets deleted when I delete a comment.

Here is a part of the threaded comments model, rest are all just methods so I have skipped them

```
class ThreadedComment(Comment):
    title = models.TextField(_('Title'), blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, default=None,
        related_name='children', verbose_name=_('Parent'), on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    last_child = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('Last child'))
    tree_path = models.TextField(_('Tree path'), editable=False,
        db_index=True)

    objects = CommentManager()
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Comment: What database engine are you using? Do you have e.g. `ON DELETE CASCADE` set in your DB?

Comment: What version of Django are you using? The cascade behaviour only changed in  1.3 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#configurable-delete-cascade)

Comment: I am using Django 1.3 and MySQL. On delete cascade is set in the db

Answer (score 1):

Threaded comments are a textbook example of DELETE CASCADE. You have a hierarchical structure, so if a parent of a comment is deleted, all the children need to be deleted as well. Otherwise, they're orphaned and your hierarchy is broken. In particular with comments, you can't just assign a child comment to a new parent, because they're often contextual and wouldn't make sense out of context from the comment the reply was posted for.

If you take a look at comment sections on websites across the Internet. When comments are threaded *and* commenters are allowed to delete their comments (in fact most websites *don't* let you delete your comments), they never *actually* delete the comment. Instead the content is simply changed to something like "*This comment has been deleted*". That way, the content is technically gone, satisfying either the user or the moderator, *but* it still hangs around for the sake of the hierarchy.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, once a comment is deleted all its children also have to be deleted. But what I want to do is if the comment is deleted then not delete the comment's parent delete. That's why I wanted to set `on_delete = models.SET_NULL` for the parent foreign key. It does not make sense to delete a comment's parent while delete the comment

Comment: Django doesn't do that. DELETE CASCADE deletes anything that has a foreign key *to* what's being deleted, not the foreign keys on that object itself. If the parent is being deleted, you've got some bug in your code somewhere -- it's not DELETE CASCADE.

Comment: I don't know why am I seeing this behavior because I was deleting a child comment and the parent also got deleted. I am using the threadedcomments app but there seems to be no bug in that

Comment: @ChrisPratt is right, delete cascade does the good job for you (when parent is deleted, all "children" get deleted). Maybe the bug comes from a **cycling** bug in the threads tree, or from the last_child field (which is obscure to me)?